# deleting character from a string one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i've been trying to create an effect like a string is being typed in my webpage. In other words that string will appear character by character. so I did this using jquery and succeded .
the code I used is something like this,

```
$(function() {
  var string = "Coming Soon|",
      stringCount = 0;

  setInterval(function(){
    $('.main_section_animate span').append(string[stringCount]);
    stringCount += 1;
  },100);
})
```

Note that the `span` tag is empty, nothing is in there.

Problem is now I'm trying to delete the string character by character, backwards. I've tried using `setInterval` and `replace(string[stringCount],'')`, selecting the main section span and main section `span.text()` but it didn't work and gave some weird results.

And also there are other thing I tried but mainly some combinition of `text()` with replace
so, anyone can help me out with this?

Comment: Can you show the code in which you were trying to delete the character? That might be helpful for further debugging.

Comment: You should read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably clear that interval to get the intended result, see: https://jsfiddle.net/2mj5zp7h/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main_section_animate">
<span></span>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  var string = "Coming Soon|",
      stringCount = 0;

  var animation = setInterval(function(){
    $('.main_section_animate span').append(string[stringCount]);
    stringCount += 1;
    if(stringCount>=string.length) {
        clearInterval(animation);
        animation = setInterval(function(){
            $('.main_section_animate span').text(string.substr(0,stringCount));
            stringCount -=1;
          if(stringCount<0)
            clearInterval(animation);
        },100);
    }
  },100);
})
```

Comment: Hehehe, same time ! Longer than me but exactly the same result :)

Answer (score 2):

can be:

```js
let str = 'Coming Soon |';

const $span = $('.main_section_animate span');

$span.html(str);

const animation = setInterval(() => {
  str = str.slice(0, -1)
  $span.html(str)
  
  !str.length && clearInterval(animation)
}, 100)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_section_animate">
<span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:** Change code.

This is a solution for you :)

Use `split()`;

```js
const str = "Coming Soon ...";
let timer;

function deletingEffect() {
 let word = str.split("");
 var loopDeleting = function() {
          word.pop();
          document.getElementById('word').innerHTML = word.join("");
          timer = setTimeout(loopDeleting, 200);
 };
 loopDeleting();
};

deletingEffect();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_section_animate">
<span id="word"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's generally bad practice to set many timeouts like that, as opposed to using an interval (which you then clear when the "loop" is finished).

Comment: Correct :) Edited

Answer (score 0):

Use `.slice()` and a simple `for` loop to get what you need.

```js
let str = 'Coming Soon|';
for (let i = -1+str.length; i > 0; i--) {
  let delay = 100*(str.length-(i+1))
  setTimeout(()=>{
    $('.main_section_animate span').html( str.slice(0, i) );
  }, delay);
}
```

Notice the `for` loop starts at `.length` and walks downwards (`i--`) while `i > 0`. This gives you an easy way to use `str.slice()`.

Also notice the removal of `setInterval` which is a waste of CPU in your case. Instead, just set a one-shot `setTimeout` for each removal.

Finally, use `.html` instead of `.append`.